# Using `static` keyword with Structured Binding

Tags: c++, static, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm trying to use C++17 structured binding to return a pair of values and I want those values to be both `static` and `const` so that they are computed the first time the function they're in is called and then they maintain their uneditable values for  the lifetime of the program. However when I do this I get the `error: a structured binding cannot declare an explicit storage class` error and I'm not sure why or how to fix it. A minimum working example is below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

static const std::pair<double, double> pairReturn()
{
    return {3,4};
}

int main()
{
    static const auto [a, b] = pairReturn();

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: static structured bindings were added to C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a bit confusing, but structured binding to static variables is just not supported with c++17. Either use a different solution, or c++2a. A different solution could just be an additional line:

```
static std::pair pr = pairReturn();
auto &[a, b] = pr;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll just  return pairs or structs for now and use them directly.